# Is replacing a value during iteration of a mapping safe in Python?

Tags: python

Is code like this **guaranteed** to work in Python?

```
d = {k: 2 * k for k in range(10)}

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = v + 1
```

As far as I know, deleting a key doesn't work, and neither does adding a key?

I know that I can work around this problem by rebuilding the dict (by using a comprehension, for example).

Edit: I'm looking for a reference showing this to be guaranteed to work in Python (not, for example, that it happens to work in the current implementation of CPython).

Comment: Yes it's totally safe :)

Comment: @alfasin Thanks, but I'm actually looking for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) warns about adding and deleting:

> Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries.

If changing the value for an existing key were also dangerous, I'm sure they'd mention that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine. It's the *structure* of the iterable you don't want to change during iteration. Updating *values* of existing keys in the iterable is perfectly safe. You could also write

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = v + 1  # Using v in place of d[k] on the right
```

or

```
for k in d:
    d[k] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but do you have a reference that shows that this is guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant docs tell us that [dict.items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), "which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes".

Let's see what that means.

```py
for k, v in d.items():
    print(d[k] is v)  # True
```

Both `v` and `d[k]` point to [the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/3694363) in memory. Since integers are [immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056598/3694363), `d[k] = d[k] + 1` will change the reference:

```py
for k, v in d.items():
    print(d[k] is v)  # True
    d[k] = d[k] + 1
    print(d[k] is v)  # False
```

So the expected behavior is that `v` points to the object that `d[k]` was referencing before the assignment. But that is the only quirk to keep in mind.

Knowing that, we can predict all sorts of behavior:

1. `v` gets its value before each iteration, so we can modify other values safely:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(d[k] is v)  # True
    if k + 1 in d:
        d[k + 1] = d[k + 1] + 1  # d[k + 1] will later become v
```

2. if `d[k]` is an immutable object, its alteration changes both `d[k]` and `v`:

```
d2 = {1: [1], 2: [2]}
for k, v in d2.items():
    print(d2[k] is v)  # True
    d2[k].append(3)
    print(d2[k] is v)  # True
    print(d2[k] == v)  # True
```